# How does Rails determine Rails.configuration.root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, root, inherited

Or rather, how does the determination work?

It takes place with the [definition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/46a22ceaff1c8dc8e5a8f5acf6bb9865e46b7768/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L359) of the `base.called_from` in `/lib/rails/engine.rb`:

```
def inherited(base)
    unless base.abstract_railtie?
      Rails::Railtie::Configuration.eager_load_namespaces << base

      base.called_from = begin
        call_stack = caller_locations.map { |l| l.absolute_path || l.path }

        File.dirname(call_stack.detect { |p| !p.match?(%r[railties[\w.-]*/lib/rails|rack[\w.-]*/lib/rack]) })
      end
    end

  super
end
```

The invocation of `Kernel#caller_locations` returns an Array of `Thread::Backtrace::Location`-objects, right?

First, I don't understand the idiom in the block passed to map:

```
l.absolute_path || l.path
```

Does it want to ensure that if `l.absolute_path` is nil then at least `l.path` is element of the result of the `map`-Enumerator ? But why shouldn't `l.absolute_path` not exist?

Second, I don't understand the construct composed out of the `detect`-Enumerator and the regex (-operator).

The `detect`Enumerator takes the first element for which the expression, here `!~`, is true. Okay.

But how does the expression, which is true if a path `p` doesn't match either

```
railties[\w.-]*/lib/rails
```

"or" (pipe)

```
rack[\w.-]*/lib/rack
```

In other words: Rails.application.root is the first path that doesn't match one of the two regex-patterns. Correct?

But if so, then: why?

(And what method, if I may ask, is `super` in this context?)

Thanks

von Spotz

Comment: `super` is most likely [`Rails::Railtie#initialize`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/070d4afacd3e9721b7e3a4634e4d026b5fa2c32c/railties/lib/rails/railtie.rb#L209).